# Alternative for Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(mainActivity) pre android 3.0

Tags: android, notifications

I have in my application a service the notify the user using a notification , i read about the
[Responding to Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#HandlingNotifications) but this method work for android API 11 and above is there a way to make the same thing on pre Android API 11.

Comment: Can't you just launch your Main Activity?